# How soon can I get a Cloyster in Shining Pearl?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

Cloyster was not in the original Gen IV pokedex, but it is now available in the remakes.

Looking at datamining sites, I found these capture locations for its pre-evolution (Shellder):

| Location | Method | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Route 205 - South | Super Rod | 20 - 40 |
| Valley Windworks | Super Rod | 20 - 40 |
| Fuego Ironworks | Super Rod | 20 - 40 |
| Grand Underground - Fountainspring Cave | Underground | 58 - 63 |
| Grand Underground - Riverbank Cave | Underground | 58 - 63 |
| Grand Underground - Still-Water Cavern | Underground | 58 - 63 |

It seems that the Super Rod can only be obtained after defeating the Elite Four.

So, is that the soonest I can get a Cloyster or is there any other way to get one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement to get Cloyster (and Shellder) is either a Super Rod, or the National Pokédex(for the three Grand Underground locations).  As both require you to defeat the Elite Four, the answer to your question is **Yes**.  (Note: the Super Rod *also* requires the National Pokédex, so really the singular answer is the National Pokédex).

Comment: I finally beat the Elite Four and tried to get the Super Rod, but I still had to get the National Dex before the 2 NPCs blocking the way to the NPC giving the Super Rod (near the Battle Tower) moved away.

Comment: Yes, good point - I hadn't known that when I wrote the answer, but similarly discovered the same over the weekend!  (Thanks, drifloon... sigh)